# @Embeddable Composite Key is not throwing integrity exception in with spring data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, composite-key, embeddable

I have used Spring Data JPA and @Embedabble to create the composite key.
And one Base class BaseDate will be extended by all the Entity.

sysCreationDate will be generated during insertion (not null and non-updatable)

save user is working fine for the first time but there are 3 issues here-

1. During the second call instead of throwing an exception it is updating the sysUpdateDate and userType
2. During the first call sysUpdateDate is not null (@UpdateTimestamp)
3. During the second call in response it returns the sysCreationDate as null

Below is the code-
Embeddable class

```
@Embeddable
public class CompKey implements Serializable {  
    @Column(name ="USER_ID")
    private String userId;
    @Column(name ="USER_NAME")
    private String userName;    
    public CompKey(String userId, String userName) {
        super();
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public CompKey() {
        super();
    }
    //Getters /Setters /Equual and Hashcode
}
```

Base Class for Date

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseDate {    
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "SYS_CREATION_DATE",  updatable=false, nullable=false)
    private Calendar sysCreationDate;
    @Column(name = "SYS_UPDATE_DATE")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Calendar sysUpdateDate; 
    public BaseDate(Calendar sysCreationDate, Calendar sysUpdateDate) {
        this.sysCreationDate = sysCreationDate;
        this.sysUpdateDate = sysUpdateDate;
    }
    public BaseDate() {
    }   
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Entity Class

```
@Entity
public class User extends BaseDate{ 
    @Column(name = "USER_TYPE")
    private String userType;
    @EmbeddedId
    private CompKey compkey;
    
    public User() {
        super();
    }
    public User(Calendar sysCreationDate, Calendar sysUpdateDate, String userType, CompKey compkey) {
        super(sysCreationDate, sysUpdateDate);
        this.userType = userType;
        this.compkey = compkey;
    }   
    //Getters and setters
}
```

Repo -

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, CompKey> {
}
```

Service and Controller -

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepo userRepo;

    public User saveUser(User user) {
        
        return userRepo.save(user);
    }

    public Optional<User> getUser(CompKey key) {
        
        return userRepo.findById(key);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    
    @PostMapping("/save")
    public User saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        
        return userService.saveUser(user);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/get")
    public Optional<User> getUser(@RequestBody CompKey key) {
        
        return userService.getUser(key);
    }
```

Input -

```
{
    "userType": "K",
    "compkey": {
        "userId": "1002",
        "userName": "ASDF"
    }
}
```

Output 1)-

```
{
    "sysCreationDate": "2021-01-08T18:09:28.802+00:00",
    "sysUpdateDate": "2021-01-08T18:09:28.802+00:00",
    "userType": "K",
    "compkey": {
        "userId": "1002",
        "userName": "ASDF"
    }
```

2. 

```
{
    "sysCreationDate": null,
    "sysUpdateDate": "2021-01-08T18:10:43.206+00:00",
    "userType": "K",
    "compkey": {
        "userId": "1002",
        "userName": "ASDF"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your controller methods for saving/updating a user?

Comment: To point 2: According to [this discussion](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/do-not-populate-updatetimestamp-field-when-entity-gets-created/2613) it is intended to set `@UpdateTimestmp` during persisting an entity.

Answer (score 2):

The integrity constraint violation exception is not thrown because your Spring repository just updates the object.

Spring repositories do not differentiate between insert and update. There is only one general-purpose method -- `save`. By default, this method *persists* (inserts) a new object **only when a primary key is `null` or `0`**; otherwise, it *merges* (updates) into an existing object. You always have a primary key set, so it always calls `merge`, which updates the second time.

Its basic implementation in `SimpleJpaRepository` looks like:

```java
    @Transactional
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
        Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null.");
        if (this.entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            this.em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return this.em.merge(entity);
        }
    }
```

The key part is `isNew` method with its default implementation like:

```java
    public boolean isNew(T entity) {

        ID id = getId(entity);
        Class<ID> idType = getIdType();

        if (!idType.isPrimitive()) {
            return id == null;
        }

        if (id instanceof Number) {
            return ((Number) id).longValue() == 0L;
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Unsupported primitive id type %s!", idType));
    }
```

The available solutions are:

1. call `EntityManager` directly.
2. implement [Persistable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html) interface from Spring and implement your own `isNew` to inform a Spring repository whether your object is new or was already persisted.
3. use a surrogate primary key (`long`, `@GeneratedValue`) and a unique constraint on your logical key

I would recommend the third solution (with a surrogate primary key) as it's simple and has better extensibility. For example, it will be easier to add a foreign key referencing your entity.

There also is a solution with calling `find` first, just to check if the object exists in a database. However, this solution is prone to a **race** issue (two concurrent REST requests to create a new object, both call `find`, both receive null, thus both save, and one data is lost/overwritten).

For @UpdateTimestamp, you've already got a comment, and for @CreationTimestamp null, please, post your controller.

Comment: By reading this answer: I can imagine, that problem 3 belongs to problem 1: The entity gets updated, in the request data the `sysCreationDate` field is `null` and so the field gets overwritten ... by `null`. Possible solution: Mark the column as "not updatable" (`@Column(/* ... */ updatable = false)`)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I have updated the code with the service and controller